# Reshaping the data with unite() does not produce expected results

Tags: r, tidyr

The goal is to turn a very wide data frame containing over a hundred columns of x,y,z positions, into a data frame containing just 3 columns: x, y, and z.

I have used unite() successfully to reshape a very wide data frame into a narrower one but for some unusual reason this doesn't work here.

```
d2 <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llorban/tracking/master/Upward%20motion%2C%20HF%20Left%202019-04-02%2002.56.19%20PM_008.csv"), skip = 6, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyr)

# Merge dataframe of tracks into one dataframe
Xpos <- grep(glob2rx("X*"), colnames(d2))
Ypos <- grep(glob2rx("Y*"), colnames(d2))
Zpos <- grep(glob2rx("Z*"), colnames(d2))

collapsed_data <- unite(d2, "Xpos", Xpos)
collapsed_data <- unite(d2, "Ypos", Ypos)
collapsed_data <- unite(d2, "Zpos", Zpos)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are you expecting `unite` to do? It takes a data frame, the name (can be bare or quoted) of a new column, and the names of columns to be pasted together to form the new column. It seems like you're expecting something other than that

Comment: @camille yes that is what I am expecting but that is not what happens

Comment: FYI it's probably not related, but you had a closing parenthesis in the wrong place—should have been after the URL text to close off `url()`. I just corrected it

Comment: Good point, thank you!

Comment: I'm not getting any such error with `tidyr` v 0.8.3. Also not sure if it's related, but you're reassigning `collapsed_data` by uniting `d2` each time, rather than successive calls to `unite` on `collapsed_data`.

Comment: I also tried running it without assigning collapsed_data with no luck:

Comment: unite(d2, "Xpos", Xpos)
    unite(d2, "Ypos", Ypos)
    unite(d2, "Zpos", Zpos)

Comment: @akrun, that was marked as off-topic because I did not articulate the problem clearly

Comment: Could you provide sample data using `dput` to prevent us  from downloading it fromGitHub. The repo may get deleted affecting usability of this question in the future.